# Pycharm Debugging Django runserver- Can't Connect from phone

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2012, pycharm

I'm trying to connect to my development server (local django runserver) while running from pycharm. I have a custom build of an android app that points to my ip address and the phone is on the same network.

When I use visual studio and python tools to run my django application my phone connects to my PC just fine.

When I use Pycharm my phone can't make a connection to the server.

Does anyone know what the difference might be between these two environments that might be causing this issue?

I'm on windows 8 using the latest version of pycharm. Pycharm is working fine for testing locally I just can't get my phone to connect to django's web server. In pycharm I'm using a *Django Server Run Configuration*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that my Pycharm configuration is using the loopback ip address 127.0.0.1 while the visual studio configuration is using the all ip 0.0.0.0. Switching my Pycharm configuration to use 0.0.0.0 solved my problem...